# AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'merge'

Tags: python, user-interface, attributeerror

This is my code:

```
class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.geometry("600x400+30+30")

        self.wButton = Button(self, text='Product Price List', command = self.OnButtonClick)
        self.wButton.pack()


    def OnButtonClick(self):
        self.top = Toplevel()
        self.top.title("Product Price List")
        self.top.geometry("300x300+30+30")
        self.top.transient(self)
        self.wButton.config(state='disabled')


        self.topButton = Button(self.top, text="Import Price list CSV", command = self.OnImport)
        self.topButton.pack()

        self.topButton = Button(self.top, text="Import Price Adjustment CSV", command = self.OnImport2)
        self.topButton.pack()

        self.topButton = Button(self.top, text="Import Price Adjustment CSV", command = self.OnImport3)
        self.topButton.pack()

        self.topButton = Button(self.top, text="Save As", command = self.OnSaveAs)
        self.topButton.pack()

        self.topButton = Button(self.top, text="CLOSE", command = self.OnChildClose)
        self.topButton.pack()

    def OnImport(self):
        self.a = askopenfilename()       
    def OnImport2(self):
        self.b = askopenfilename()
        self.c = self.a.merge(self.b, how='left', left_on='Dynamic_spcMatrix', right_on='Dynamic_spcMatrix' )
    def OnImport3(self):
        self.d = askopenfilename()
        self.d = self.d.dropna(axis=0)
        self.g = self.d.groupby('Dynamic_spcMatrix')['Attribute_spcName'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.astype(str))) #join attributes usin commas
        self.c['Attribute_spcName'] = self.c['Dynamic_spcMatrix'].map(g)
        self.c = self.c[['Type', 'Name', 'Currency_spcCode', 'Product_spcCfg_spcModel_spcId', 'Product_spcName', 'Attribute_spcName', 'Matrix_spcType', 'Start_spcDate', 'End_spcDate', 'Original_spcList_spcPrice', 'Max_spcSale_spcPrice', 'Min_spcSale_spcPrice', 'String_spcMatrix_spcColumn_spc1', 'String_spcMatrix_spcColumn_spc2', 'String_spcMatrix_spcColumn_spc3', 'String_spcMatrix_spcColumn_spc4','Number_spcMatrix_spcColumn_spc1']]
    def OnSaveAs(self):     
        self.dlg = asksaveasfilename(confirmoverwrite=False)
        self.fname = self.dlg
        if self.fname != '':
            f = open(self.fname, "a")
            new_text = time.time()
            f.write(str(new_text)+'\n')
            f.close()     
        self.c.to_csv(self.fname, index=False)

    def OnChildClose(self):
        self.wButton.config(state='normal')
        self.top.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Window(None)

    window.title("Create Csv")

    window.mainloop()
```

it gives following error in `OnImport2`:

```
self.c = self.a.OnImport.merge(self.b, how='left', left_on='Dynamic_spcMatrix', right_on='Dynamic_spcMatrix' )
```

> AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'merge'

I'm beginner for python and all other languages. Can you please help me to solve this?

Comment: what do you expect `self.a.merge` to do?

Comment: to merge the two csv files (a and b). :( may be I'm wrong. @ConfusedByCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like `asksaveasfilename`, `askopenfilename` returns a string (which Python 2 calls `unicode` when used to (potentially) store non-ASCII text).  If you want to read (CSV data out of) it, you have to do so explicitly—presumably via what appears to be `pandas` that you’re using for merging/output.

Comment: Can you explain it further please? @Davis :)

Comment: @sithara: You're going to have to be more specific; what do you need here beyond "a file's name and its contents are distinct"?

Comment: Mm.. :( thnku @Davis